# ReactJS - Show a preloader before the image is loaded

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have this component in which it is rendered data coming from a json. Everything is working right. But I would like to insert a loader:  `<i className="fa fa-spinner"></i>` before the image is loaded. The loader should disappear afterwards as well. How I do?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

var data = require('./db.json');

class Biografy extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      photo: ""
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      photo: data.biography[0].photo
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <i className="fa fa-spinner"></i>
        <img src={this.state.photo && `/images/${this.state.photo}`} alt="" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Biografy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

img src has onLoad event that you need in this case.
Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

var data = require('./db.json');

class Biografy extends Component {

    state = {
      photo: "",
      loading: false
    }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      photo: data.biography[0].photo
    })
  }

  render() {
 const style = this.state.loading ? {} : {visibility: 'hidden'}
 const {loading} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {!loading && <i className="fa fa-spinner"></i>}
       <img src={this.state.photo && `/images/${this.state.photo}`} alt="" 
         onLoad={() => this.setState({loading: true})}
         style={style}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Biografy
```

Comment: it isn't working. There is an error message: loading is not defined

Comment: see my edit. This is working fine now.Just copy paste code as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Since it looks like you're using the state of `this.state.photo` to determine whether it's loading or not, you could simply add that conditional before rendering the `i` tag:

```
{!this.state.photo && <i className="fa fa-spinner"></i>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    { !this.state.photo
        ? (<i className="fa fa-spinner"></i>)
        : (<img src={this.state.photo && `/images/${this.state.photo}`} alt="" />)
    }
```

That means if there is photo, you show the image. If there is not, you show the loader.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap it with suspense tags,

this is exactly what suspense is for;

As per the tutorial I read:

> With the SVG and JS way, the JS to parse our HTML and add the SVG may fire before React has time to mount it's components. So we have to find a way to parse the HTML once React has mounted its components.

You will need to install the 'react-fontawesome' library as well as the 'free-solid-svg-icons' library from fontawesome

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

Then you can insert the following code

```
import React, { Component, Suspense } from 'react'

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSpinner } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

var data = require('./db.json');

class Biografy extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      photo: ""
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      photo: data.biography[0].photo
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSpinner} size="2x" spin />}>
        <div>
          <img src={this.state.photo && `/images/${this.state.photo}`} alt="" />
        </div>
      </Suspense>
    )
  }
}


export default Biografy
```

Once you do this, you can delete the library import from your html and selectively choose the icon that you need

See the following documentation/tutorials for more info:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-font-awesome-5-with-react

https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome

Comment: There is not any error message. Simply nothing appears on the screen

Comment: are you sure you're importing the style sheet for the loading spinner? if the loading spinner isn't rendered, then you will see a blank loading screen.

Comment: The spinner was appearing before I had inserted your code.

Comment: The spinner css was imported from the parent file 'index.js' with this line:
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' and everyting was working nice

Comment: Now I cheked again and I noticed that afterwards there is an error message: Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components) or a class/funcion (for composite components) but got:symbol. pointed do: ReactDOM.render(

Comment: Sorry, it's not working for me either, I'll have to look into debugging this later.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Apparently, there are issues with the asynchronous nature of the primary functionality of react and the loading and parsing of the HTML and CSS of the fontawesome library.